# insert thread in python script

Tags: multithreading, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

i want to ask how to insert threading in python script because when i'm inserting thread duplicate result process in python function

example using 2 thread

```
thread 1

a
b
c
```

```
thread 2

a duplicate from thread 1
b duplicate from thread 1
c duplicate from thread 1
```

already try this script but still duplicate result thread

```
def request():
    for n in u():
        for p in p():
                appid = n+'&insert='+p
                url = f"{base_url}{appid}"
                print(url)

                response = requests.get(url,proxies=proxy)
                unformatted_data = response.json()                                

                if "wrong" in str(response.content):
                    print(''+name+':'+linec+'=Salah')
                    pass
                elif "success" in str(response.content):
                    print(''+name+':'+linec+'=Sukses')
                else:
                    print(''+str(unformatted_data)+'')
    return

for x in range(2):
    t = Thread(target=request, args=())
    t.start()
    print('Waiting for the thread...')
    t.join()
```

and the result duplicate

```
thread 1
a
b
c
thread 2
a
b
c
```

but i want to thread 1 and thread 2 process same function in python not duplicate every thread

example

```
thread 1 & thread 2

a
b
c
```

Comment: It sounds as if you have a list of _tasks_ that you want your program to perform, and you are asking how to make several threads share the work, while cooperating with each other to ensure that each task is performed exactly one time. Is that correct? If so, then you might want to learn about "thread pools." https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool

Comment: not work i can't insert that still duplicate result